# Sending email using libcurl - follow-up 2

Tags: c++, c++14, email, curl

This question is a continuation of: [Sending email using libcurl - follow-up](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/140409/sending-email-using-libcurl-follow-up)

Does this code have any problems? Can I improve it?

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <curl/curl.h>

class EmailAddress 
{
public:
    EmailAddress(const char *email)
        : email_{std::string(email)}
        {
        }

    EmailAddress(const std::string &email)
        : email_{email.size() ? "<"  + email + ">" : ""}
        {
        }

    EmailAddress(const std::string &email, const std::string &displayName)
        : email_{email.size() ? "<" + email + ">" : ""},
          name_{"\"" + displayName + "\""}
        {
        }

    std::string domain() const
        {
            return email_.substr(email_.find('@') + 1);
        }

    explicit operator const char *() const
        {
            return email_.c_str();
        }

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const EmailAddress &email)
        {
            return out << email.name_ << " " << email.email_;
        }

private:
    std::string email_;
    std::string name_;
};

typedef std::vector<EmailAddress> EmailAddresses;
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const EmailAddresses &emailAddresses);

class Email
{
public:
    Email(const EmailAddress   &from,
          const EmailAddress   &to,
          const std::string    &subject,
          const std::string    &body,
          const EmailAddresses &cc = EmailAddresses())                
        : from_{from}
        , to_{ to }
        , cc_{cc.empty() ? EmailAddresses(1, to) : cc}
        , subject_{subject}
        , body_{body}
        {
        }

    CURLcode send(const std::string &url,
                  const std::string &userName, 
                  const std::string &password);

private:
    struct StringData {
            std::string msg;
            size_t bytesLeft;
            StringData(std::string &&m) : msg{m}, bytesLeft{msg.size()} {}
            StringData(std::string  &m) = delete;
        };

    static std::string dateTimeNow_();
    static size_t payloadSource_(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp);
    std::string generateMessageId_() const;
    std::string setPayloadText_();

    EmailAddress from_, to_;
    EmailAddresses cc_;
    std::string subject_, body_;
};

CURLcode Email::send(const std::string &url,
                     const std::string &userName,
                     const std::string &password)
{
    CURLcode ret = CURLE_OK;

    struct curl_slist *recipients = NULL;

    CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();

    StringData textData { setPayloadText_() };

    if (curl) {
        std::ostringstream cc;
        cc << cc_;

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERNAME,     userName.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PASSWORD,     password.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL,          url     .c_str());

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USE_SSL,      (long)CURLUSESSL_ALL);
        //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO,       "/path/to/certificate.pem");

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAIL_FROM,    (const char *)from_);
        recipients = curl_slist_append(recipients,   (const char *)to_);
        recipients = curl_slist_append(recipients,   cc.str().c_str());

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAIL_RCPT,    recipients);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, payloadSource_);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA,     &textData);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD,       1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,      1L);

        ret = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        if (ret != CURLE_OK) {
            std::cerr << "curl_easy_perform() failed: "
                      << curl_easy_strerror(ret)
                      << std::endl;
        }

        curl_slist_free_all(recipients);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }

    return ret;
}

std::string Email::dateTimeNow_()
{
    const int RFC5322_TIME_LEN = 32;

    std::string ret;
    ret.resize(RFC5322_TIME_LEN);

    time_t tt;

#ifdef _MSC_VER
    time(&tt);
    tm *t = localtime(&tt);
#else
    tm tv, *t = &tv;
    tt = time(&tt);
    localtime_r(&tt, t);
#endif

    strftime(&ret[0], RFC5322_TIME_LEN, "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z", t);

    return ret;
}

std::string Email::generateMessageId_() const
{
    const size_t MESSAGE_ID_LEN = 37;

    tm t;
    time_t tt;
    time(&tt);

#ifdef _MSC_VER
    gmtime_s(&t, &tt);
#else
    gmtime_r(&tt, &t);
#endif

    std::string ret;
    ret.resize(MESSAGE_ID_LEN);
    size_t dateLen = std::strftime(&ret[0], MESSAGE_ID_LEN, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S", &t);

    static const std::string alphaNum {
        "0123456789"
        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" };

    std::mt19937 gen;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> distr(0, alphaNum.length() - 1);
    std::generate_n(ret.begin() + dateLen,
                    MESSAGE_ID_LEN - dateLen,
                    [&]() { return alphaNum[distr(gen)]; });

    return ret;
}

size_t Email::payloadSource_(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
    StringData *text = reinterpret_cast<StringData *>(userp);

    if ((size == 0) || (nmemb == 0) || ((size*nmemb) < 1) || (text->bytesLeft == 0)) {
        return 0;
    }

    if ((nmemb * size) >= text->msg.size()) {
        text->bytesLeft = 0;
        return text->msg.copy(reinterpret_cast<char *>(ptr), text->msg.size());
    }

    return 0;
}

std::string Email::setPayloadText_()
{
    std::string ret = "Date: " + dateTimeNow_() + "\r\n";

    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << "To: "   << to_   << "\r\n"
           "From: " << from_ << "\r\n"
           "Cc: "   << cc_   << "\r\n";
    ret += oss.str();

    ret +=
        "Message-ID: <" + generateMessageId_() + "@" + from_.domain() + ">\r\n"
        "Subject: " + subject_ + "\r\n"
        "\r\n" +
        body_ + "\r\n"
        "\r\n";

    return ret;
}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const EmailAddresses &emailAddresses)
{
    if (!emailAddresses.empty()) {
        auto &it = emailAddresses.begin();
        out << *it;

        while (++it != emailAddresses.end()) {
            out << "," << *it;
        }
    }

    return out;
}

int main()
{
    Email email({ "from@email.x", "FromName" },
                  "to@email.x",
                  "Subject",
                  "Body"  );

    email.send (  "smtp://smtp.email.x:25",
                  "UserName",
                  "Password"  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A quick note regarding long messages handling in your `payloadSource_` function as I stumbled upon the same problem. The problem is that if your message is too long (long body or attachment in base64 coding for instance), then `(nmemb * size) >= text->msg.size()` is always `false` and you return 0 without copying anything to the curl buffer. You then send an empty mail instead of your message.

I managed to solve that by replacing `text->msg` by a buffer from which I can read bytes, and changing the `payloadSource_` function to something like this:

```
StringData*text=reinterpret_cast<StringData*>(userp);
size_t len=std::min(size*nmemb,text->bytesleft);
if(size*nmemb<1){return 0;}
if(text->bytesleft>0){
    text->bytesleft-=std::min(len,text->bytesleft);
    text->in.read(reinterpret_cast<byte*>(ptr),len);
    return len;}
return 0;
```

`text->in` is an object containing a buffer with the message (like a char*) and a pointer to the position in that buffer (at first, the beginning of that buffer).

`in.read` reads `len` bytes from `in`, and stores the current position in its position pointer, so that next call to payloadSource will start reading from `in` at that position.

You now call `payloadSource` several times until you copied all your message in the curl buffer and return 0 (which signals end-of-file to the library).

I had a look at the `read_callback` function here https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/post-callback.html to help.

Hope that helps!
Good luck,
Cheers

V.

Comment: I am afraid to make a mistake. Could you make more complete example please?

Answer (score 0):

A minor nit would be that in your constructor you check for emptiness of the provided string via an implicit `size() == 0`

```
EmailAddress(const std::string &email)
    : email_{email.size() ? "<"  + email + ">" : ""}
    {
    }
```

It would be more descriptive to use `empty()`

```
EmailAddress(const std::string &email)
    : email_{email.empty() ? "" : "<"  + email + ">"}
    {
    }
```